# Vuejs vue-easy-slider before-next question

Tags: vue.js, slider

I'm trying to stop the slider looping content using before-next.

The docs say this takes a function that returns true to allow the next slide to show.

If I pass a method in the slider html

```
<slider :before-next="check()" :v-model="Slide">
  <slider-item v-for="(item, index) in items"></slider>
</slider>
methods: {
check: function () {
 if(this.Slide = this.items.length -1) {
 return {
   false
 } else {
   return {
     true
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I get an expected function got boolean error

If a pass

```
 methods: function () {
   this.Slide < this.items.length - 2
 }
```

I get no error but also a slider that still loops

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting this works.

```
  <slider :before-next="() => Slide < gallery.length - 1" :before-previous="() => Slide > 0"  :v-model="Slide">
    <slider-item v-for="(item, index) in items">
      <img src="gallery" />
    </slider-item>
  </slider>
```

It now doesn't loop